# Validate NSString for Hexadecimal value

Tags: cocoa, nsstring

I'm working on a custom NSFormatter. 
I need to verify user input step by step... i thought to check by `isPartialStringValid:` if the string contains only permitted chars "0123456789ABCDEF". 
How can i verify this condition ? is there a way with NSString function to check if a string contain only some chars ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Does this method work for you?

```
    NSString *string = @"FF";

    NSCharacterSet *chars = [[NSCharacterSet 
        characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789ABCDEF"] invertedSet];

    BOOL isValid = (NSNotFound == [string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:chars].location);
```

Answer (score 10):

### Swift 5

```
extension String {
    var isHexNumber: Bool {
        filter(\.isHexDigit).count == count
    }
}

print("text1".isHexNumber) // false
print("aa32".isHexNumber) // true
print("AD1".isHexNumber) // true
```

Answer (score 5):

You can create a custom `NSCharacterSet` that contains the permitted characters (`+ characterSetWithCharactersInString:`) and then test the string against it with `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:`. If the returned range is equal to the entire range of the string, you have a match.

Another option would be matching with `NSRegularExpression`.

Sample code Swift:

```
func isValidHexNumber() -> Bool {
    guard isEmpty == false else { return false }
    let chars = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789ABCDEF").inverted
    return uppercased().rangeOfCharacter(from: chars) == nil
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In **swift 2.1** you can extends String in this way:

```
extension String {

  func isValidHexNumber() -> Bool {
    let chars = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "0123456789ABCDEF").invertedSet
    guard self.uppercaseString.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(chars) != nil else {
        return false
    }
    return true
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift one-liner without adding any extensions:

```
myString.allSatisfy(\.isHexDigit)
```

Using a `keypath` predicate was introduced in Swift 5.2 prior to that you could use:

```
myString.allSatisfy({ $0.isHexDigit })
```